# Cannot run jupyter notebook in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed jupyter notebook using:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

It seemed to work but I got the error:
The directory '/home/user1/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user1/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag

When I run it:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the error:
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 8] Exec format error

Comment: sibling site is a better place for such questions https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`pip3 install jupyter --user`

This will install jupyter to your home directory. This removes the ownership issue. In my case the installation directory is:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages.

I use Linux Mint, which is a fork of Ubuntu.